# Spring framework with standard JDBC in java

Tags: spring, jdbc

I have a question and I hope you answer it please.

I want to use Spring framework with Standard jdbc like this

```
"SELECT usernmae FROM users WHERE username='" + usename + '"
```

Is it possible to do that I donot want to use prepared statement. It is just sample query.

Comment: Standard JDBC is *not* vulnerable to SQL injection.  Bad programming is. Spring will make no difference either way.  Also, `JdbcTemplate` *is* standard JDBC, just with a slightly nicer interface.

Comment: I have project and I want to show that using JDBC with Spring could lead to sql injection. Is is possible to do that wiht spring and standard jdbc (I mean without using preparedstatment,, it is sample jdbc) with spring.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly. This question is only two hours and old asking the same thing again just an hour later is not considered acceptable. If you have anything further to add then add to this question. Thanks.

Comment: I am so sorry becuase this first time I ask q question in the nice website. But I am still please wait for any help from any one to answer my question

Comment: @user813056: We can't help you to demonstrate X, because X is incorrect. You can't show something that is wrong to be right.

Comment: I didn't catch your meaning but I will explain to you in diferent way. Is it possible to use the following with JDBC in spring or not Query q = session.createQuery("from Customer where lower (last_Name) ='" + customer_Name + "'");

Comment: I am confused: Before editing this question was about SQL Injection, JDBC and Spring. Now it is about Spring and JDBC? What is your question? If you can use JDBC with Spring?

Maybe you want to read documentation? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ok leave SQL injection. My question I can use sample JDBC with Sring the same example above. That's it.

Comment: Unless you've got some *very* strict validation code in place *and you use it consistently* (difficult to get right, frankly) you'll end up in trouble if Little Bobby Tables comes knocking (see http://xkcd.com/327/). **Use A Prepared Statement.** Really. We're serious; this is utterly utterly best practice.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is no more or less vulnerable to SQL injection than any other SQL connection mechanism.  Vulnerability to SQL injection falls on the hands of the people who write the code.  JDBC templates provide a way to manage the connection with the database not necessarily protect you from SQL injection.  You are still more than capable of writing crappy code with a JDBC template that is vulnerable to SQL injection.

**Edit**  To address the update to your question.  You can do that, there is a simple [query](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor%29) method in the JDBC template, but doing so would make you vulnerable to SQL injection.  The simple answer: **always use prepared statements**.  The only time you can safely avoid using them is if you are not including any input in the query that can from the user.  However, you are far better just using a prepared statement even in those cases on the off chance that your assumption is incorrect or it changes down the road.  Always, always, always use prepared statements.  There is also some performance benefits to using them as the SQL engine can cache the compiled statement for later use, rather than having to recompile the SQL statement each time.

Comment: I have project and I want to show that using JDBC with Spring could lead to sql injection. Is is possible to do that wiht spring and jdbc?Also I can use standard jdbc (I mean without preparedstatment) with spring